# Recommended and updated opengl book

Tags: c++, opengl

I am looking for a good updated opengl book :)

I have the *Opengl Programming Guide 8th Edition*, its pretty bad actually :\

all the source code example is a huge mess and some of the code just make's error's and whatnot (some of the examples even uses variable that was not even declared or typed in the wrong variable's.

What is the most recommended book that out now?

Comment: *"[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask): To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where … every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite \_\_\_\_\_\_?”, […] your question is just a rant in disguise: “\_\_\_\_\_\_ sucks, am I right?”"*

Comment: not opengl but webgl: http://www.amazon.com/WebGL-Programming-Guide-Interactive-Graphics/dp/0321902920/

Comment: Try _OpenGL 4.0 Shading Language Cookbook_. Good luck.

Comment: @Zeta I just said my opinion, and asked for your's for another book not for you to comment about the red book.
Im programming in c++ so why WebGL?

OpenGL 4.0 Shading Language Cookbook teaches opengl from the beginning?

Comment: Completely disagreed that the above mentioned book is bad. Conversely, it's one of the best.But it’s not a tutorial but a general guide and hardly suitable for noobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the most recommended book that out now?

That would be the OpenGL Specification. ;)

But seriously: you can't go wrong with the **OpenGL Superbible** in the latest revision (6th). Personally I stopped using the Red Book years ago and found the Superbible much more readable for beginners.

At some point, what now is a remark in jest, will become a reality: if you seriously want to get into OpenGL, there is no way around reading and understanding the actual specification.

Comment: Is it updated?
I will use Opengl Specification when I will know how to use the basics of it lol :)

Comment: @NaorHadar: It's currently updated to cover core GL 4.3 - this should hold you for quite a while. ;)

Comment: I wish you got an ebook version with the print book as standard - like what you do with Manning books.

Comment: The new SB is better. SB5 was really bad.